# CoreData View like in sql or oracle

Tags: ios, core-data

I've got a core data model in which I've got objects with a certain data, all in the same entity. For my tableView controller, I'd like to merge all objects with the same date to one object, like a view in sql or oracle. The fetchedResultController should fetched these merged objects and display in the tableView.

Is this possible and does everyone have a working example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this. You can simple add protocol for each model. For example

```
@protocol CellDisplayProtocol {
  - (NSString *)dateForShow;
}
```

Add this protocol to each model and implement. Model will returns neccesary data;
Then in 'cellForRowAtIndex' you can use protocol method "dateForShow" to display "Date"

Instead of merge you are putting all request results to the one array.

Comment: sounds nice, can you show me an example of how fetchedResultController  fetch data from the protocol?

Comment: no, fetchedResultController  doesn't have protocol, you should add protocol to managed object models

Comment: So there's no way to fetch data like view and use fetchedResultsController?

Comment: no, coredata have other ways for this. Not easy ways, but have

Comment: thanks' do you have an example or at least a search topic?
only to know, there's a way isn't helpful at all.